Bounds on Rademacher complexity of intinite class of bounded functions
Suppose I have a class $\mathcal{F}$ of bounded functions $f : \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ , i.e. there exists $M < \infty$ such that for all $ x \in \mathcal{X}$, for some norm $ \lVert \cdot \rVert $, we have $ \lVert f(x) \rVert \leq M $. Furthermore, suppose that the number of members of the class $\mathcal{F}$ is infinite. What are some known bounds on the Rademacher complexity of $\mathcal{F}$?
